Empty window on "Disk setup" step when installing Ubuntu
I can not install Ubuntu. On step "Disk setup" there is an empty window and an error is occurring:
✓ ExecutablePath
/snap/ubuntu-desktop-bootstrap/171/bin/subiquity/subiquity/cmd/server.py

✓ Package
subiquity 171

✓ Problem Type
Bug

✓ Title 
block probing crashed with ValueError

✓ Traceback
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "/snap/ubuntu-desktop-bootstrap/171/bin/subiquity/subiquity/server/controllers/filesystem.py",
line 1319, in_probe await asyncio.wait_for(self._probe_once_task.task, probert_timeout)
File "/snap/ubuntu-desktop-bootstrap/171/usr/lib/python3.10/asyncio/tasks.py",
line 445, in wait_for return fut.result()
File "/snap/ubuntu-desktop-bootstrap/171/bin/subiquity/subiquitycore/context.py",
line 166, in decorated_async return await meth(self, **kw)
File "/snap/ubuntu-desktop-bootstrap/171/bin/subiquity/subiquity/server/controllers/filesystem.py",
line 1295, in_probe_once self.model.load_probe_data(storage)
File "/snap/ubuntu-desktop-bootstrap/171/bin/subiquity/subiquity/models/filesystem.py",
line 1994, in load_probe_data self.reset()
File "/snap/ubuntu-desktop-bootstrap/171/bin/subiquity/subiquity/models/Filesystem.py",
line 1492, in reset self.process_probe_data()
File "/snap/ubuntu-desktop-bootstrap/171/bin/subiquity/subiquity/models/Filesystem.py",
line 1512, in process_probe_data self._orig_config = storage_config.extract_storage_config(self._probe_data)
File "/snap/ubuntu-desktop-bootstrap/171/lib/python3.10/site-packages/curtin/storage_config.py",
line 1420, in extract_storage_config tree = get_config_tree(cfg.get('id'), final_config)
File "/snap/ubuntu-desktop-bootstrap/171/lib/python3.10/site-packages/curtin/storage_config.py",
line 313, in get_config_tree for dep in find_item_dependencies(item, sconfig):
File "/snap/ubuntu-desktop-bootstrap/171/lib/python3.10/site-packages/curtin/storage_config.py",
line 283, in find_item_dependencies _validate_dep_type(item_id, dep_key, dep, config)
File "/snap/ubuntu-desktop-bootstrap/171/lib/python3.10/site-packages/curtin/storage_config.py",
line 230, in_validate_dep_type raise ValueError( ValueError: Invalid dep_id (nvme-controller-nvmeo) not in storage config

My laptop is Dell G3 15 3500.
Is NVMe not supported or something?
Screen-photos: https://photos.app.goo.gl/uV7GC7WbrEpuMMXp6



Ubuntu version LTS: ubuntu-24.04-desktop-amd64.iso
Downloaded from the official Ubuntu website.
No problem when installing it on VirtualBox.
The problem is only on a physical laptop.
It is trying to install from the pendrive.
The pendrive has GPT and fat32.
Laptop booting from the pendrive successfully.
The laptop has 2 GPT drives:

SSD
HDD
The laptop SATA setting was set to AHCI.
These drives are not empty.
Windows 11 is installed on SSD.
HDD has Windows 10.

Does Ubuntu can be installed only on an empty drive nowadays for real?
My steps:

puting pendrive to USB port
booting from pendrive
selecting Try or install Ubuntu on GRUB screen
clicking next button in setup window
stucking on "Disk setup" step without any choice and getting mentioned error

"Disk setup" step shows only question "How I want to install Ubuntu" or sth like that. Without Manual or Erase... options

Please edit the question and add the critical info of what version of Ubuntu are you trying to install and how are you tying to do the install? What steps and how was the boot media created?

If it was me; I'd consider the release (you've provided no clues there), if the media validation completed (checking that is I consider cheap insurance) etc... but you've provided no clues as to what if anything you actually tried, OR are using.

For nvme a fix has been issued via this PR, tracked by launchpad bug 2063162.
The issue should be fixed in 24.04.1
